# Is it possible to extend gifs to support audio?

Tags: file-formats

**Can the file format gif be extended to support audio as well?**

I was looking into gifs that support audio and the main gif sites with "audio gifs" are just looping videos. The problem is how memory inefficient videos are.

Would it be possible to extend the gif file format to also support videos? Are there any good resources to doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Your question will likely be closed soon because it doesn't show reasonable research. If you want to represent video, you use a video file format. GIF is an image file format (so no audio) that supports a limited amount of animation. Using it for short video clips is possible but not really smart.

Comment: No: but there's no reason videos should be less memory efficient than gifs! GIF is a pretty horrendous file format and a good h264 file, even with audio, should be much smaller.

Comment: Modern video formats like WebM/AV1 are insanely good, unlike the bloated GIF format from the 80s. But the trick is to choose a small resolution and to apply lots of compression. Note that modern media formats are “containers” for a separate video stream and audio stream, and you often have various choices to mix and match codecs as desired.

Comment: Yeah, after a bit of searching, looks like most sites just convert gifs into mp4 files for storage compression. AV1 seems like the most efficient video compression out there.

Answer (score 3):

In theory, you can add any feature to any format.

In practice, GIF images are so widespread and the new feature, while vaguely related, is so far from the core functionality of the standard format that you will never get sufficient buy-in from the rest of the world to extend it; particularly since many other convenient video+audio formats already exist.